# Elasticsearch multiple fields query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm asking for your help.
elasticsearch create search query
first, search field is keyword type

data

```json
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "search_event",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_score" : 5.179434,
        "_source" : {
          "search_keyword" : [
            {
              "search" : "or",
              "keyword" : "developer",
              "type" : "18"
            }
       ]
    },
    {
        "_source" : {
          "search_keyword" : [
            {
              "search" : "or",
              "keyword" : "tail"
            },
            {
              "search" : "or",
              "keyword" : "cap"
            },
            {
              "search" : "and",
              "keyword" : "developer"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

When searching,
Must be keyword=developer and search=or

```json
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "search_keyword.keyword": {
              "value": "developer"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "search_keyword.search": {
              "value": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, 'keyword=developer and search=and' but also a search.
how do I write a query?

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "search_event",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_score" : 5.179434,
        "_source" : {
          "search_keyword" : [
            {
              "search" : "or",
              "keyword" : "developer",
              "type" : "18"
            },
            {
              "search" : "or",
              "keyword" : "tail"
            },
            {
              "search" : "or",
              "keyword" : "cap"
            },
            {
              "search" : "and",
              "keyword" : "developer"
            }
          ]
        }
       ]
    }
```

i wan't search 'keyword=developer and search=and' documents
only 'keyword=developer and search=or' documents

Answer (score 0):

use below query

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ --> note instead of `filter`, it's `must` clause.
        {
          "term": {
            "search_keyword.keyword": {
              "value": "developer"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "search_keyword.search": {
              "value": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is the same even if must is used instead of filter

Comment: @vane can you add your index mapping, sample and expected document

Comment: two field is keyword type

Comment: @vane did you get a chance to solve issue? if yes would appriaciate if you can accept answer :)

Comment: haven't solved it yet ㅠㅠ

Comment: @vane what issue you are facing?